# Find Index of List of Tuples from 1 item

Tags: c#, list, indexing, tuples

Please consider a List of Tuples in C#. This relates to the original Tuple (not Value Tuple). How can I get the index of the List, if I know one of the Items within the List of Tuples?

```
        List<Tuple<double, int>> ListOfTuples2 = new 
        List<Tuple<double, int>>();

        double doubleTuple = 5000;
        int intTuple = 7;

        ListOfTuples2.Add(Tuple.Create(doubleTuple, intTuple));
        ListOfTuples2.Add(Tuple.Create(5000.00, 2));
        ListOfTuples2.Add(Tuple.Create(5000.25, 3));
        ListOfTuples2.Add(Tuple.Create(5000.50, 4));
        ListOfTuples2.Add(Tuple.Create(5000.25, 5));


        /* How can I get the Index of the List if 
        doubleTuple = 5000.25 ?  */
```

Comment: What had you tried? It should be easy with fx linq

Comment: I mean the index of the List. In this case if doubleTuple = 5000.25 the Return should be 2 (as it's the 3rd and the first is 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `FindIndex` method of the list accepting a predicate as argument

```
int index = ListOfTuples2.FindIndex(t => t.Item1 == 5000.25);
if (index > = 0) {
    // found!
}
```

`FindIndex` returns `-1` if no such item is found.

---

But you might consider using a dictionary instead. If the collection is big, it finds entries much faster than a list. The retrieval times in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): `List<T>` is `O(n)`, `Dictionary<K,V>` is `O(1)`. However, items in a dictionary are not ordered and have no index. In addition, keys must be unique. If you need ordered items, stick to the list.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<double, int>{
    [doubleTuple] = intTuple,
    [5000.00] = 2,
    [5000.25] = 3,
    [5000.50] = 4,
    [5000.25] = 5
}

if (dict.TryGetValue(5000.25, out int result)) {
    // result is 3; and contains the value, not the index.
}
```

You can also add entries with

```
dict.Add(5000.75, 8);
```

If you are sure that the dictionary contains an entry, you can simply retrieve it with

```
int result = dict[5000.25];
```

---

Also, if you are dealing with prices, consider using the `decimal` type. If has been created specifically for financial and monetary calculations. The `double` type stores the values as binary numbers. `0.1` (decimal) is `0.000110011001100110011001100110011...` (binary), i.e., `double` introduces a rounding error, solely by converting a decimal constant into its binary representation, whereas `decimal` stores each decimal of the constant as is. `double` is okay (and faster) for scientific calculations. It makes no difference whether a temperature is 29.7 or 29.69999999999 degrees, since you can measure it with a very limited precision anyway (maybe 1%).

---

C# 7.0 has added `ValueTuple` types plus a simple syntax for tuple types and tuple values. Consider replacing the `Tuple` class with this new feature.

```cs
var listOfValueTuples = new List<(double, int)> {
    (doubleTuple, intTuple),
    (5000.00, 2),
    (5000.25, 3),
    (5000.50, 4),
    (5000.25, 5)
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! It works! I am a newbie and was stuck with this!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to get all indexes you can write following code:

```
var indexes = ListOfTuples2.Select((tuple, index) => new {tuple, index}).Where(o => Math.Abs(o.tuple.Item1 - 5000.25) < 1e-5).Select(o => o.index - 1);
foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Note that comparing two floats can return unpredictable results, so I used comparing using `Math.Abs` method